# Writing a filter for a regex that works in fail2ban-regex on the command line

Tags: fail2ban

I have entries like these in apache2 error.log

```
[Thu Jan 12 09:18:51.078445 2023] [core:error] [pid 47992] [client 152.89.196.211:53158] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)
[Wed Jan 11 06:01:09.820582 2023] [core:error] [pid 30833] [client 185.225.74.55:39856] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/bin/sh)
[Wed Jan 11 17:16:49.643509 2023] [core:error] [pid 41882] [client 152.89.196.211:52746] AH10244: invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh)
```

I got this to work on the command line:

```
fail2ban-regex test.log '.*\[client <HOST>:\d+\] AH10244.*$'
```

Every time I try to stick the regex into a .conf file like so:

```
[Definition]
 
failregex = .*\[client <HOST>:\d+\] AH10244.*$
 
ignoreregex =
```

fail2ban complains:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : filter.conf
ERROR: No failure-id group in 'filter.conf'
```

I've looked in the man pages and online but I can't find an explanation of what this message is trying to say, or how to fix it.

**The Questions**

1. How do I wrap a .conf file around this regex?
2. What does that error mean?
3. Could I (how would I) use the pre-defined stuff in apache-common.conf to make this regex more robust?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
fail2ban-regex test.log ./filter.conf
```

I had my test files (`test.log` and `filter.conf`) in my home dir.  When I ( from the home dir ) issued the command:

```
fail2ban-regex test.log filter.conf
```

I assumed that I was referencing `./test.log` and `./filter.conf` but I think that fail2ban was looking in the `filter.d/` folder to try to find `filter.conf`.

I found that if `filter.conf` was in the `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/` folder, then `fail2ban-regex test.log filter.conf` succeeded.